# what does mean that <<mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too>>

Tags: linux, command, manual

i am noob in Linux
in manual for command i got the phrase "mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too" and i have searched that mandatory arguments is that arguments have to be specified but "i coudn't understand what does "mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too"  means.. would you give me the explication and example?

Sorry... I need to study how aks the question hier
I taped man mv in linux for search the information
ans in description 
Rename Source to Dest, or move Source to Directory.
Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
hier i can't understand the phrase Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux, it's often possible to specify the same command-line option as either a long option (that is, the form with `--` and a word) or a short option (the form with `-` and a letter).  For example, with `ls`, you can specify `ls -a` or `ls --all`, and they are completely equivalent.

Some options are specified to take an argument.  For example, when you use the `-w` or `--width` argument to `ls`, you must tell it how wide you want the text to be.  In this case, the argument is mandatory.  This text is telling you that although the manual page doesn't list an argument for `-w`, only for `--width`, it is required for both and has the same meaning.  Putting this text in the manual page simply avoids duplicating a lot of needless text and makes the manual page tidier and easier to read.

There are also optional arguments, such as the argument to `--color`.  In such a case, if you fail to specify it, some default value (in this case, `always`) is assumed.

Comment: Questions about Linux and its tools are off topic and shouldn't be answered here.

Comment: Thakns you so much i got it :)